# How to reference Data in an Array/Hash from JSON Response in Perl

Tags: perl, reference, dump

I'm writing some Perl Code and I am a totally noob (specialized in PHP and JS). I'm retrieving some data from a JSON API Request and I want to reference the data and build some HTML-Options for a select field. But I just can't figure out how to reference the values from the JSON Response.

```perl
#!/bin/false

use strict;
use warnings;

use LWP::UserAgent;
use HTTP::Request;
use JSON;
use Encode;

use vars qw(@parameters $new $mode $metainfo);

use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper);

sub main
{
    if ($mode ne 'EDIT') {
        return;
    }

    my @pagetypes = _getPagetypes();
    if (scalar @pagetypes == 0 || ! defined \@pagetypes) {
        return "";
    }

    my $html = "";

    foreach (@pagetypes) {
        my $pagetype = $_;

        return Dumper @pagetypes;

        $html .= sprintf(
            '<option value="%s">%s</option>',
            $pagetype->{"identifier"},
            encode_utf8($pagetype->{"label"}),
        );
    }

    return $html;
}

##
# Get Pagetypes from API
##
sub _getPagetypes
{
    my $url = sprintf(
        "%s/page-types/",
        $ENV{'URL'}
    );

    my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new(ssl_opts => { verify_hostname => 1 });
    my $header = HTTP::Request->new(GET => $url);
    my $request = HTTP::Request->new('GET', $url, $header);
    my $response = $ua->request($request);

    my @data = decode_json($response->content);
    my @pagetypes = @data[0]->{'pageTypes'};

    return @pagetypes;
}
```

Where it says `return Dumper $pagetypes;` the following output is written:

```
$VAR1 = [
    {
        'label' => 'Projektsteckbrief',
        'identifier' => 'pagetype-profile'
    }
];
```

I tried `$pagetype->{"label"}` and `$pagetypes[0]->{"label"}` and so much more...but I just don't know how to get the label and the identifier there.

**update:**

I tried to implement the pagetypes manually and this is working fine with the `main()` method (without the Dumper Call):

```perl
sub _getPagetypes
{
    my @pagetypes = (
        {
            identifier => "pagetype-profile",
            label => "Projektsteckbrief",
        },
    );

    return @pagetypes;
}
```

**UPDATE 2**:

So I got a new problem...it's not working completely yet, but Bl00D4NGEL's response was a great help anyway!

So my code looks like this right now:

```perl
#!/bin/false

use strict;
use warnings;

use LWP::UserAgent;
use HTTP::Request;
use JSON;
use Encode;
use Project::Util::Api;

use vars qw(@parameters $new $mode $metainfo);

sub main
{
    if ($mode ne 'EDIT') {
        return;
    }

    my @pagetypes = _getPagetypes();
    if (scalar @pagetypes == 0 || ! defined \@pagetypes) {
        return "";
    }

    my $html = "";

    foreach my $pagetype (@pagetypes) {
        # selection will be automatically set by Imperia
        $html .= sprintf(
            '<option value="%s">%s</option>',
            $pagetype->[0]->{"identifier"},
            encode_utf8($pagetype->[0]->{"label"}),
        );
    }

    return $html;
}

##
# Get Pagetypes from API
##
sub _getPagetypes
{
    my $response = Project::Util::Api->sendRequest("/ajax/imperia/page-types/de/");
    my @pagetypes = $response->{"pageTypes"};

    return @pagetypes;
}

$new = main();
```

The problem is now that only one item is displayed.
So `$pagetype` in my foreach loop looks like it's still the array with all of the items inside and `$pagetype->[0]` then gives me only the first item out of the array.

When I use `for` instead of `foreach` like this:

```perl
for ( $a = 0 ; $a <= 10 ; $a++ ) {
    $html .= sprintf(
        '<option value="%s">%s</option>',
        @pagetypes[0]->[$a]->{"id"},
        encode_utf8(@pagetypes[0]->[$a]->{"label"}),
    );
}
```

I get 10 items of 200, but I just cant figure out how to get the length of the array `@pagetypes`.
I tried the following:

```perl
# 500 Server error (because of long loading?)
for ( $a = 0 ; $a <= @pagetypes[0] ; $a++ ) {

my $pagetypesLength = @pagetypes;
# Only 2 items are displayed
for ( $a = 0 ; $a <= @pagetypes ; $a++ ) {
for ( $a = 0 ; $a <= $pagetypesLength ; $a++ ) {
for ( $a = 0 ; $a <= scalar @pagetypes ; $a++ ) {
for ( $a = 0 ; $a <= length @pagetypes ; $a++ ) {
```

**UPDATE 3 (FINALLY WORKING)**:

So finally I managed to get it working. Final code following:

```perl
#!/bin/false

use strict;
use warnings;

use Encode;
use Project::Util::Api;

use vars qw(@parameters $new $mode $metainfo);

sub main
{
    if ($mode ne 'EDIT') {
        return;
    }

    my $items = _getData();
    if (0 == scalar @$items) {
        return "";
    }

    my $html = "";

    # $#{$items} is last index of array reference $items
    for (my $i = 0 ; $i <= $#{$items} ; $i++) {
        if (defined $items->[$i]->{"id"}) {
            # option selection will be automatically set by Imperia
            $html .= sprintf(
                '<option value="%s">%s</option>',
                $items->[$i]->{"identifier"},
                encode_utf8($items->[$i]->{"label"}),
            );
        }
    }

    return $html;
}

##
# Get Pagetypes from API
##
sub _getData
{
    my $response = Project::Util::Api->sendRequest("/ajax/imperia/page-types/de/");

    return $response->{"pageTypes"};
}

$new = main();
```

Comment: Your question discusses `return Dumper $pagetypes;` but the code doesn't show a `$pagetypes` scalar variable, it shows a `@pagetypes` array. Therefore we can only guess at what you actually are doing to get the dump that you showed. Please post the actual snippet of code that produces the dump you are seeing.

Comment: You're right, I'm sorry. I tried to access the variable with a `$` and didn't undo it. I updated the code extract now and added another information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the $pagetype variable is actually an array ref (looking at the Dumper at least it looks like it)
So what should probably solve this issue is this:

```
    my $pagetype = $_;

    $html .= sprintf(

    '<option value="%s">%s</option>',
    $pagetype->[0]->{"identifier"},
    encode_utf8($pagetype->{"label"}),

    );
```

Comment: Thank god, that works! I though you access this array with `$pagetype[0]`. I guess the `->` needs to be used because its ref?

Comment: Yes, certainly. You should check out this perl maven article: https://perlmaven.com/array-references-in-perl

Comment: thank you very much! Can I ask you to check UPDATE 2 in my initial question? With your comment I only get the first element of the array. Thank you very much!

Comment: Looks like you're accessing @pagetypes wrong. if you want to access an array or hash element you need to type $variable[0] or $variable{'key'} to access it. You tried accessing the variable by using @pagetypes[0]->[$a]->{"id"}, which is wrong, therefore a syntax error occured.

Comment: nah, @pagetypes[0]->[$a]->{"id"} is just working fine. The problem is, that I dont know how to get the right code for the array length in the for loop. and with foreach the single $pagetype is always the full array of @pagetypes in dumper :(

Comment: to get the length of an array in perl use scalar(@array), but if I get your scenario right the @pagetype array only has one element (in Index 0) and in there, there are multiple values, am I right with this? If so, what you might need to do is something like `my @values = @{$pagetypes[0]}` and then do `for my $value (@values) { ... }` to iterate over the elements.